# How do I perform exact string match on python

Tags: python, string, compare, match

I have a set of words

words = {'thanks giving', 'cat', 'instead of',etc...}

I need to search exactly these words in table column 'description'

```
--------------------------------|
ID  | Description               |
--- |---------------------------|
1   | having fun   thanks giving| 
----|---------------------------|
2   |  cat eats all the food    |
----|---------------------------|
3   |  instead you can come     | 
--------------------------------

def matched_words(x,words):
   match_words =[]
  for word in words:
     if word in x:
       match_words.append(word)
  return match_words

df['new_col'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x:matched_words(x,words))
```

desired output :

```
----|---------------------------|-------------------|
ID  | Description               |matched words      |
--- |---------------------------|-------------------|
1   | having fun   thanks giving|['thanks giving']  |
----|---------------------------|------------------ |
2   |  cat eats all the food    |['cat']            |
----|---------------------------|-------------------|
3   |  instead you can come     | []                |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I'm getting matches only single tokens like ['cat']

Comment: Are you sure that you have a dictionary? Are you sure it looks like this?

Comment: A dictionary looks like `{key: value, key: value, etc.}`. Your dictionary just has values, no keys. It looks more like a list.

Comment: I think he meant set instead of dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean they're not exact matches? Give examples of some matches you got that you shouldn't. Do you mean you want to match whole words, not just parts of words?

Comment: You can split the description into a list of words. Then you can use `if word in list_of_words:`

Comment: But that won't work for something like `instead of`, which is multiple words. You could use a regular expression with `\b` at the beginning and end, to match word boundaries.

Comment: @Barmar Its a set

Comment: @Barmar Where Can I use regular expression is it before split ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should give you the results you're looking for:

```
import re

words = {'thanks', 'cat', 'instead of'}
phrases = [
    [1,"having fun at thanksgiving"],
    [2,"cater the food"],
    [3, "instead you can come"],
    [4, "instead of pizza"],
    [5, "thanks for all the fish"]
]

matched_words = []
matched_pairs = []
for word in words:
    for phrase in phrases:
        result = re.search(r'\b'+word+'\W', phrase[1])
        if result:
            matched_words.append(result.group(0))
            matched_pairs.append([result.group(0), phrase])
            print()

print(matched_words)
print(matched_pairs)
```

The relevant part, that is, the `regex` bit `re.search(r'\b'+word+'\W', phrase[1])`, is searching for cases in which our search string is found beginning at a word boundary `\b`, or `empty string`, and ending in a non-word character `\W`. This should ensure that we find only whole-string matches. No need to do anything else to the text you want to search.

Of course, you can use anything you want instead of `words`, `phrases`, `matched_words` and `matched_pairs`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: am getting output as a lift it works for matching the string

Comment: list* in the previous comment.I'm trying to get output as another column in table as  1,"having fun at thanksgiving",[]
               2,"cater the food",[]
               3, "instead you can come",[]
               4, "instead of pizza",['instead of']
               5, "thanks for all the fish",['thanks'] .If it matches more than one it will be in the list as ['thanks','cat']. Unable to get this output

Comment: Your Question specifically states "for word in words: if word in x: print word", and then goes on to suggest that what you are asking for is a way to get exact matches. Please edit your Question to make it apparent that you are asking how to get the output in a list. I've updated my answer to reflect what I think you are asking for. Is this correct? Also, in the future, try to be as specific as possible as to your desired result. Both of these make it more helpful to answer and for future folks to find the help they need when they find this Question.

Comment: Actually, rereading your comment, I'm not sure I _do_ understand what you are looking for. Can you please edit your Question to more clearly describe what that is? Include the code you've tried, using Code Markup (4 spaces before each line of your code), and a clear description of the desired result.

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest opening this new stuff up as a different question. Your Question here is titled `How do I perform exact string match on python` and I think the Answers here are good, solid answers to that Question. If you'd like, you can come back here and add a comment referring me (or anyone else) to the new Question. I'll certainly be happy to take a look at that one.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I edited your Question a tiny bit for formatting and to make the Question clear. :)

Comment: @Sid For what it is worth, while 'cat' is a word in english, it is a string in programming terms. 'thanks giving' and 'instead of' are _not_ words, they _are_ phrases, but again, in programming terms, they are strings just like 'cat'. There was a reason my edit used the word 'strings'. A single word contains no spaces, but a string can.

Comment: @sid Also, did my updated code solve your problem? If not, I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: I'm getting all the matched strings as a list.But I'm trying to see at which column that string matched like I modified in the desired output section in the question

Comment: Like the `matched_pairs` list in the code I suggested above? Note that I edited it a few hours ago, if you haven't tried the new code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
words = {'thanks', 'cat', 'instead of'}

samples = [
    (1, 'having fun at thanksgiving'),
    (2, 'cater the food'),
    (3, 'instead you can come'),
    (4, 'instead of you can come'),
]

for id, description in samples:
    for word in words:
        if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', description):
            print("'%s' in '%s" % (word, description))
```